# Aligning image to the top of a table cell

Tags: html, css, wordpress

[image]

I'm designing a wordpress page inside of the wordpress editor, and I can't figure out how to get the grey image placeholder to align to the top of the table cell. As long as the text in the left cell doesn't go below the grey image, everything is fine. But as soon as the text gets below the bottom of the image, the image pushes down. Here's the code:

```
<table border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: top;">
<img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-71" alt="webi" src="#" 
width="437"     height="114" />                                                                      
&nbsp;
<p>
SOME TEXT
</p>
</td>
<td style="width: 355px;">
<img class="alignright size-full wp-image-61"   alt="palvelut_kuvapaikka" 
src="#"  
align="top" width="355" height="355" /> 
 </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: By setting `style="vertical-align: top;"` on the second cell, too?

Answer (score 28):

Just set the `vertical-align: top` property on the right `td` as well?

Comment: Yeah I actually had it there, but still the same problem.

Comment: `vertical-align: top` works perfectly fine with your exact code [in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D5MMS/)

Comment: I can second that - http://jsfiddle.net/BXMVB/ it works.. If it doesn't - then you have some other styles that interfere

Comment: Most probably there is another CSS than forcing it to center. Try this: vertical-align: top!important

Answer (score 3):

to align it to the top in a table you need to use in css: `vertical-align: top`